# ANTLR4 C# runtime extremely slow at parsing

Tags: c#, dsl, antlr4

I'm migrating my custom DSL from `GoldParser` to `ANTLR4`, but I'm stuck at the parsing step because it takes too much to finish. A source of 1000 lines is parsed in 34 seconds versus the milliseconds range I had in GoldParser.

This is the C# code I use for parsing:

```
var input = new AntlrInputStream(prg);
var lexer = new PCLexer(input);
var tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
var parser = new PCParser(tokens);       
var tree = parser.programma(); // root rule is "programma"
```

I suspect the problem is in the grammar which has a lot of ambiguities, indeed it was the reason why I decided to migrate it from GoldParser (not being able to further improve it, I realized it was a lot easier to rewrite it in Antlr4 and do not care of ambiguities).

My question is: is there anything I can do to have milliseconds order-of-magnitude parsing, or it's just normal that ANTLR4 is inherently slow? I'm new to Antlr and I don't know what to expect.

Regading the grammar, it's a sort of pseudo-C:

```
    grammar PC;                                    

    fragment Number : [0-9] ;

    fragment DoubleStringCharacter  : ~["\r\n] ;
    fragment SingleStringCharacter  : ~['\r\n] ;
    fragment DoubleStringCharacterM : ~["] ;  
    fragment SingleStringCharacterM : ~['] ;

    BlockComment : '/*' .*? '*/' -> skip ;
    LineComment  : '//' ~[\r\n]* -> skip ;
    WhiteSpaces  : [\t\u000B\u000C\u0020\u00A0]+ -> skip ; 

    Identifier   : [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]* ; 
    Quote        : '\''  ;
    DoubleQuote  : '"'   ;
    NullLiteral  : 'null' ;
    BoolLiteral  : 'true' | 'false' ;
    IntLiteral   : (Number)+ ;
    FloatLiteral : (Number)* '.' (Number)+ ;

    StringLiteral    :     DoubleQuote DoubleStringCharacter*   DoubleQuote ;
    StringLiteralJs  :     Quote       SingleStringCharacter*   Quote       ;
    StringLiteralM   : '@' DoubleQuote DoubleStringCharacter*   DoubleQuote ;
    StringLiteralJsM : '@' Quote       SingleStringCharacter*   Quote       ;

    Or_op        : 'or' | '||'  ;
    And_op       : 'and' | '&&' ;
    Not_op       : 'not' | '!'  ;
    Not_eq       : '!=' | '<>'  ;

    programma : interfaccia? dichiarazione* ;

    interfaccia : 'interfaccia' '{' oggettoInterfaccia* '}' ;

    oggettoInterfaccia : Identifier Identifier '{' definizioneProprieta* '}' ;

    definizioneProprieta : Identifier '=' valoreProprieta ';' 
                         | oggettoInterfaccia; 

    valoreProprieta : BoolLiteral | IntLiteral  | FloatLiteral | StringLiteral | StringLiteralM | Identifier ;

    dichiarazione : dichiarazioneReference 
                  | dichiarazioneUsing 
                  | dichiarazioneClass
                  | dichiarazioneFunzione 
                  | dichiarazioneVariabile 
                  ;             

    dichiarazioneReference : 'reference' StringLiteral ';' ;
    dichiarazioneUsing     : 'using' Identifier '=' StringLiteral ';' ;
    dichiarazioneClass     : 'class' Identifier ';' ;

    dichiarazioneFunzione : Identifier Identifier '(' parametri ')' '{' stmList '}' ;

    parametri : parametro (',' parametro)* ;

    parametro : Identifier 
              | Identifier Identifier
              ;       

    dichiarazioneVariabile : Identifier listaVariabili ';' ;                            

    listaVariabili : variabile (',' variabile)* ;

    variabile : Identifier 
              | Identifier '=' exprOrArray
              ;

    stmList : stm* ;

    stm  : blocco
         | dichiarazioneVariabile
         | etichetta
         | istruzioneIf
         | istruzioneWhile
         | istruzioneFor
         | istruzioneDo                              
         | istruzioneGoto
         | istruzioneBreak
         | istruzioneContinue
         | istruzioneReturn
         | expr ';'              
         | assegnamento ';'               
         | ';'          
         | 'ConnectEvent' '(' Identifier ',' Identifier ',' Identifier ')' ';'
         | istruzioneTry
         ;

    blocco : '{' stmList '}' ;

    istruzioneIf : 'if' '(' expr ')' stm ( 'else' stm )? ;

    istruzioneFor : 'for' '(' stm condizioneFor ';' incrementoFor? ')' stm ;
    condizioneFor : expr? ; 
    incrementoFor : expr 
                  | assegnamento 
                  ;

    istruzioneWhile : 'while' '(' expr ')' stm ; 

    istruzioneDo : 'do' stm 'while' '(' expr ')' ;    // TODO si deve aggiungere ';' ?          

    etichetta          : Identifier ':' ;    
    istruzioneGoto     : 'goto' Identifier ';' ;
    istruzioneBreak    : 'break' ';' ;
    istruzioneContinue : 'continue' ';' ;
    istruzioneReturn   : 'return' exprOrArray ';' | 'return' ';' ;
    istruzioneTry      : 'try' blocco 'catch' '(' Identifier ')' blocco ;

    assegnamento : Identifier '=' exprOrArray
                 | Identifier '[' expr ']' '=' exprOrArray
                 | Identifier '.' Identifier '=' exprOrArray
                 ;

    exprOrArray : expr 
                | '{' exprList '}'
                ;

    exprList : exprOrArray ',' exprList
             | exprOrArray
             ;

    expr : expr '+=' expr
         | expr '-=' expr
         | expr '?' expr ':' expr
         | expr Or_op  expr
         | expr And_op expr         
         | expr '==' expr
         | expr Not_eq expr
         | expr '<' expr
         | expr '>' expr
         | expr '<=' expr
         | expr '>=' expr
         | expr 'as' Identifier
         | expr '+' expr
         | expr '-' expr
         | expr '*' expr
         | expr '/' expr
         | expr '%' expr
         | expr Not_op expr
         | '-' expr
         | '+' expr
         | '--' expr
         | '++' expr
         | expr '--'
         | expr '++'
         | expr '[' expr ']' 
         | callFun
         | Identifier '.' Identifier '(' methodParams ')'      
         | Identifier '.' Identifier          
         | Identifier
         | literal
         | '(' expr ')'
         ;

    methodParams : methodParam (',' methodParam)* ;
    methodParam  : exprOrArray ;

    callFun : Identifier '(' methodParams ')'               
            | 'new' Identifier '(' methodParams ')'
            ;        

    literal : NullLiteral
            | BoolLiteral
            | IntLiteral  
            | FloatLiteral 
            | StringLiteral
            | StringLiteralJs
            | StringLiteralM
            | StringLiteralJsM        
            ;
```

Answer (score 2):

If your grammar had ambiguities, the Gold Parser (my understanding: LALR(1)) would not parse source text correctly. [I assume your are ignoring complaints it should produce about shift-reduce and reduce-reduce conflicts?] It would pick one of the parses. And, being LALR(1), it will do so in linear time, so it is not surprise that it is fast; this is a key utility of LALR(1) parsers.

Ambiguity in a grammar often (not always) means that there are parses you should have eliminated, but did not.  If Gold is picking among parses, and some are wrong, there is no reason to believe you are getting a correct parse.

So, in fact, if you can get the wrong answer in milliseconds with Gold, why does it matter if ANTLR gets the wrong answer somewhat more slowly?

I suggest you remove the ambiguities.  (As a starting place, your expression subgrammar looks highly ambiguous to me).  I think ANTLR will "speed up".

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes the grammar in Gold was a total mess to the point that I was unable to fix it or implement the new features I needed. Anyway in Gold it was less ambiguos than in ANTLR because in Gold you can't have left recursion, so for example the whole "expression" rule is split into a long chain of subrules. I will work more on the grammar, but please can you confirm that ANTLR4 is able to achieve high speeds (in the milliseconds range) or it's better for me to stay with a LALR parser if I need quick parsing? Thank you (and sorry for the multiple edits).

Comment: 1)  Ambiguity is a property of the grammar, not the parser generator.  2) I thought Gold was LALR(1); do I have that wrong? If I'm right, LALR(1) handles left (and right) recursion just fine.  3)  If you want a really fast parser, you want a bottom one like LALR(1), done right, it can process each token by a single table lookup, and a stack push; that's very hard to beat.   I doubt Gold is "done right", I think it is done for portabilty.    ANTLR generates what amounts to a top-down parser; these can be very fast.  I doubt you'd care about the difference, unless you process a million lines.

Comment: Yes Gold is LALR(1), and my wrong assumption was that switching from LALR to LL my grammar would magically fix by itself. I was lead to that conclusion because in ANTLR grammars are very easy to write: 1) you can use the ()* operator instead of writing chains of rules just for implementing "lists" (like arguments in a function call) and 2) no need to specify operator precedence other that writing the rules in the correct order. So if I have understood correctly ANTLR is able to handle 1) and 2) but at the expenses  of parsing time, while a LALR parser uses tables and thus is quicker.

Comment: I've built dozens of parsers.  The last thing that bothers me is defining the typical expression grammar explicitly; I just do it, they're about 20 - 30 lines of grammar specification.  Frankly, *writing* a grammar is easy;  knowing what grammar to write is lot harder.    So I don't see ANTLR as significantly easier to specify-for, and ANTLR's additional constraints (limited left recursion) for me aren't helpful.  Suggest you just bite the bullet and simply *fix* the ambiguities rather than spend all this time trying to avoid fixing them; then they'll stop being trouble.  Your move.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll follow your advice and try to fix the grammar first and later I'll decide whether to stay with Gold or move to ANTLR.